# What are the possible errors in this Object merging function?

Tags: javascript, merge

I set out to find and understand a nice way to merge objects in Vanilla JS. My requirements for the function are very simple (borrowed from [here](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/deepmerge)):

- Merge two objects `x` and `y` deeply, returning a new merged object with the elements from both `x` and `y`.
- If an element at the same key is present for both `x` and `y`, the value from `y` will appear in the result.
- The merge is immutable, so neither `x` nor `y` will be modified.

I came across [this](https://gomakethings.com/vanilla-javascript-version-of-jquery-extend/) article that seems to provide a pretty good solution. After going through the code and understanding it (for the most part), I shortened it down to the following:

```
var extend = function() {

  var extended = {};
  var length = arguments.length;

  // Merge the object into the extended object
  var merge = function(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      //Check if a property is an object and another layer of merging is required
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]') {
        extended[prop] = extend(true, extended[prop], obj[prop]);
      } else {
        extended[prop] = obj[prop];
      }
    }
  };

  // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
  while (length--) {
    var obj = arguments[length];
    merge(obj);
  }

  return extended;
};
```

From the original solution I removed the check for a deep merge as I would like to deep merge by default, and this line, present before the currently merged property value is checked for being an object:

```
if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) )
```

I don't understand this line - why should we check if the object whose properties are currently being looped through has the property from the current loop? I feel like I'm missing something.

So that's it. Are there any cases where this function wouldn't fulfil my requirements? Or break execution on any other way? Thank you.

Comment: This line bothers me a lot: Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]' - just do typeof obj[prop] === "object" for gods sake!

Comment: I agree, I questioned the authors decision to do this as well, but I'm sure there's a reason behind such a convoluted approach, I'd love to hear thoughts on why someone wouldn't just check the typeof the property.

Comment: @user2415266: Yeah, that bothered me, too. But the `extend` function above won't correctly handle arrays or dates or regexps, so a more narrow check (just raw objects) isn't necessarily out of line.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When you say won't correctly handle arrays, do you mean it won't merge the arrays or something else?

Comment: Say you have `var x = {foo: [1, 2, 3]}` and you do `o = extend(x)`. You'll end up with `x.foo === o.foo`; they share the same array, because the code above just copies the array reference. If you changed that line to `if (typeof obj[prop] === "object')`, then you'd end up with `o` being `{foo: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}}` because that `extend` doesn't handle arrays properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) )
> ```
>
> I don't understand this line - why should we check if the object whose properties are currently being looped through has the property from the current loop?

Because `for-in` loops visit all of the enumerable properties of an object, including ones it inherits from its prototype. Whether you want to copy inherited properties over depends on your use cases for your `extend` function. Apparently in the original code, they didn't want to.

Example showing the difference:

```js
var name;
var p = {inherited: "property"};
// Create an object using p as its prototype
var o = Object.create(p);
o.own = "property";

console.log("Without check");
for (name in o) {
  console.log("- " + name);
}

console.log("With check");
for (name in o) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, name)) {
    console.log("- " + name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Any idea why anyone would use Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, prop ) instead of just obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) ?

Comment: @user2415266: Two reasons: 1. In case the object doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` and so doesn't inherit `hasOwnProperty` (for instance, was created without a prototype: `var o = Object.create(null)`), or 2. In case it overrides `hasOwnProperty` with a version doing something different. #1 is a lot more likely than #2. :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder Interesting. Another thing which I'm suprised of: you are running a software consulting company, but your own website looks kind of out of date. I hope you don't feel offended, I was just wondering.

Comment: Out of curiosity - how would one loop through an object without going over the enumerable properties?

Comment: @user2415266: Been too busy, but it's on the list. It's funny you should say that, actually, because it's pretty high on the list. It's in the August/September plan.

Comment: @styke: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry - pretty tired today - what would be the best way to loop over an objects properties without going over the ones inherited by its prototype?

Comment: @styke: The `hasOwnProperty` check is a good way. Another is `Object.keys`, which returns an array containing only the object's own (not inherited), enumerable properties. That's what I usually use.